# stretching input box to fill space until button using ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using ionic 2 and trying to create a chat style layout. my current html looks like

```
<ion-footer>
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-9>
            <ion-input type="text" placeholder="start typing..." ></ion-input>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-3 align-self-end>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button ion-button icon-only>
                <ion-icon name="ios-send" ></ion-icon>
            </button>
            </ion-buttons>
        </ion-col></ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

</ion-footer>
```

this one renders a input box  and then the send button. I am trying to strech the input box to take entire space with just little margin and then the button.

if I remove the entire grid or try to put input and button in a one col then the button goes to next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.html`

```
<ion-footer>
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="start typing..."></ion-input>

<ion-buttons end>
    <button ion-button icon-only>
            <ion-icon name="ios-send" ></ion-icon>
        </button>
</ion-buttons>
</ion-footer>
```

and in `.scss`

```
ion-input {
    position: absolute;
    width: 88%;
}
```